# suggest me well designed opensource web apps in .net

Tags: .net, architecture

I found architecture  of Blogengine.net good and interesting. Are there other very well designed opensource web apps written in .Net ?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143088/open-source-c-projects-that-have-very-high-code-quality-to-learn-from

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503239/good-c-open-source-projects-to-participate-in

Comment: OP is asking for web apps only. IMO this can exist as a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for: [ASP.NET Open Source Projects](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/388/aspnet-open-source-projects/).

It has multiple categories: Blogs, Content Management Systems, Controls, Toolkits, Frameworks, Forums, Galleries, Starter Kits, Wikis, Miscellaneous and Additional Projects links:

> http://asp.net/community/projects/
>   http://www.codeplex.com/
>   http://csharp-source.net/
>   http://www.nopcommerce.com/ - Open
>   source asp.net shopping cart
>   application
>   http://www.codeplex.com/nexus - Open
>   source igoogle/pageflakes like
>   application

Answer (score 1):

Check out PunBB.Net punbbnet.codeplex.com/
It's a simple, well-designed ASP.Net forum application done in C#. You will find the code very easy to follow.